# Should i bundle both Arm64-V8a and armeabi-v7a in android app?

Tags: android

I am tring to reduce the output app file size, there are two diffrent library for my app:

Arm64-V8a and armeabi-v7a

I want to know is it require to include both of them ?

Comment: Given that you seem to know about the [64-bit Android requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) you might have also found [multiple APK](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) if you have a download app size issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid question. If you are not going to run your app on emulator and run only on Mobile devices, then you can remove armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64 libs by placing below code in project build.gradle This will definitely reduce your apk file size.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept answer, if its working the way i told.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support all devices CPU architecture you need to keep the both of them and adding ***x86*** & ***x86_64*** as well, however to reduce the APK size try the following :

1. Go to Android Studio **Menu > Refactor > Remove Unused Resources**
2. Enable the **Proguard** and set **shrinkResources** to *`true`*
3. Using **Android Bundle**, Google Play will take the rest of work by
   splitting your APK to APKS and show it to the user depends on their
   device CPU architecture